# Telegram bot: List of telegram bot commands

Tags: bots, telegram

I can not find how to get a list of commands from a telegram bot. Neither via api nor via external binding. Is it even possible?
For example. I created a list of commands to bot with help the Bot Father. Now i want to get this list from my programm to check user input a command.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bot API has a [getMyCommands](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getmycommands) method

Comment: How i missed that?! -_- Thank you very much

Comment: @newsha you could claim an answer as yours!

Write your comment as answer to this question: you deserve it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### you can use the `getMyCommands` method

Use this method to get the current list of the bot's commands for the given scope and user language. Returns Array of BotCommand on success. If commands aren't set, an empty list is returned.

| Parameter | Type | Required | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| scope | [BotCommandScope](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#botcommandscope) | Optional | A JSON-serialized object, describing scope of users. Defaults to BotCommandScopeDefault. |
| language_code | String | Optional | A two-letter ISO 639-1 language code or an empty string |